# How to use vertical scroll bar in qt design?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to ask a question which my qt centralwidget width is 1160 and height is 1242. When I run the bottom didn't show because the size is too big. I add in a vertical scroll bar in qt design but I don't know how to link it which means when I press the vertical scroll bar it didn't move to the bottom. I write in C++.

Comment: You probably want to add a QScrollArea widget to your window, put the rest of your window's content as children of a separate QWidget, and then call setWidget(theSeparateWidget) on the QScrollArea so it knows to scroll that content.  See:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html

Comment: I try to add the ScrollArea in the design UI and put all my widget inside the scroll area. Actually I don't know how to use the content. I mean like what should and put and where should I put. For example, I plan to use void setWidget but I don't know where should I put and how to use it. (void Mainwindow:: setWidget) ?

Comment: I can’t help you there.  I suggest you grep the programs that come in QT’s examples folder for QScrollArea, to get an idea about how they use it, and copy their use-patterns.